# GUARDAR IMAGEN EN UN SERVIDOR REMOTO CON JAVA NETBEANS?

Tags: java, webservice, netbeans, bufferedimage

Buenos dias queridos programadores. Lo que necesito es guardar imagen de cualquier tamaño en el servidor.
Tengo un archivo.php en el servidor que me guarda la imagen (que funciona), lo que deseo saber es cómo enviar una imagen para que reciba ese archivo.php por medio de alguna peticion http.
La imagen ya tengo en byte[]:

```
String mapa= Base64.encode(imageInByte,0);//esto es netbeans
```

deseo enviar mapa a archivo.php

Comment: NetBeans es un IDE de Java, no un framework ni nada de eso. "cómo hacer esto con Java NetBeans" es como preguntar "como hacer esto con PHP emacs".

Comment: Y en todo caso no está claro qué es lo que se pregunta: `cómo enviar una imagen para que reciba ese archivo.php` ¿la imagen recibe el PHP?

Comment: @JoelRomero cual es el problema que te esta dando

Comment: Hola a todos,, aún no he resolvido el problema. Lo dije Java Netbeans como una forma de que me entiendan que me refiero a aplicación de escritorio y que no es Android. En realidad la idea es enviar imagen a ese archivo.php. Este archivo lo recibe y guarda en el servidor.